# fiddler show encrypted https traffic

Tags: https, fiddler

I want to take a look at the direct encrypted https traffic of my requests. I got a server and 2 clients. With client 1 there are no problems. client 2 gets problems if the request exceeds a certain text-size. I was able to decrypt the traffic and found that client 1 extends my SOAP request every 3996 signs by an extra "f9c"-pattern. Client 2 is not doing this which is probably causing the problem on the serverside. But that is not all. If I use fiddler to decrypt the https request the server also throws an exception. So my guess is that the client is probably adding something on the https encryption too. That is why I want to take a look at this but I cannot figure out how to force fiddler to show this to me. I only get the http traffic if I disable https-decryption that shows my the handshake between client and server. So what can I do here?

Answer (score 0):

problem solved.
the "f9c"-pattern is just the hex value for 3996-bytes. The problem was that client 1 was correctly chunking the http-request. Client 2 on the contrary was sending a single block and just setting the content-length of the http-request. Therefore I do not need to take a look anymore on the encrypted request.